# VBA: Applying MAX on an address from UDF in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a UDF that returns the address of a range (a column without header) from a worksheet. The output is a string like "$A$2$A$5". In another worksheet, I want to apply several worksheet functions, e.g., MAX, on the corresponding range of cells A2 to A5.
The combination of MAX and the UDF leads to an error message (#Value) while when replacing the UDF with the corresponding string value: MAX($A$2$A$5) works.
Is there a way to make this work? Code:

```
Public Function SELECTH(SheetName As String, HeaderName As String) As String

   Dim ColIndex As Integer
   Dim MaxRowIndex As Integer

   ColIndex = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(1).Find(HeaderName).Column
   MaxRowIndex = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

   SELECTH = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(Cells(2, ColIndex), Cells(MaxRowIndex, ColIndex)).Address()

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a range and not a string:

```
Public Function SELECTH(SheetName As String, HeaderName As String) As Range

Dim ColIndex As Long
Dim MaxRowIndex As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
        ColIndex = .Rows(1).Find(HeaderName).Column
        MaxRowIndex = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set SELECTH = .Range(.Cells(2, ColIndex), .Cells(MaxRowIndex, ColIndex))
    End With

End Function
```